# How to use LoginName (logged in username) into SqlDataSource select command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using asp website administrator tools to create users & use them for login
I can use `<asp:LoginName runat="server" />` to show logged in username.

How can I use it (logged in username) into SqlDataSource select command (SQL syntex) ?

will be like-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE (username='USER_NAME_I_WANT')"
```

Please help me.

PS: I am using C# and for simplicity, I'd like to use as less background code as possible.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The username is stored in `System.Web.UI.Page.User.Identity.Name`. Use the value of that field in your query.

Comment: Thanks. That works but I found u cant put that directly in your SqlDataSource. To define, I had to use a parameter (I used Season parameter & before that in code-behind, I store that value in a season variable)

Answer (score 0):

Get Your Logged User Name and Password

```
 Uname = Login1.UserName;
  pass = Login1.Password;
```